# Azure Function: "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information"

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

I have an F# Azure Function that is failing, in a bizarre way, and don't know how to approach fixing the issue. I created a minimum repro of the actual case below. The test function is manually triggered and uses FSharp.Compiler.Service as a dependency, as specified in the `project.json` below:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "FSharp.Compiler.Service": "11.0.6"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `run.fsx` file looks like this:

```
open System

open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Ast
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell

let Run(input: string, log: TraceWriter) =

    // code here that uses FsiEvaluationSession
    // and runs just fine

    log.Info "I RAN"
```

So far, so good. The part that baffles me is that if I add the following function above `Run`,

```
// same dependencies as before
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell

let foo (longIdent:LongIdent) =
    // version 1
    // "FOO"
    // version 2
    // longIdent.ToString ()
    // version 3
    longIdent |> List.map string 

let Run(input: string, log: TraceWriter) =
    // same as before
```

Uncommenting section 1 alone works fine, uncommenting section 2 alone works fine, uncommenting section 3 causes hell to break loose. The function compiles, but running it causes the following exception:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.fsc-1. mscorlib: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

... which is puzzling to me, because

1. `foo` isn't even called anywhere
2. the signature and the 2nd version both use `LongIdent`, so this type doesn't seem to be the source of the problem.

Any suggestion on how to approach the problem, and what the problem itself might be, would be very appreciated - I don't even know where to start, and the same code runs perfectly fine in a local script.

Comment: So, any luck getting those `LoaderExceptions`?

Comment: This looks like `FSharp.Core` loading issue to me - when you uncomment version 3, `list<string>` appears in the type and so the runtime is forced to load `FSharp.Core`. I bet the one loaded by the functions runtime is different than the one that `FSharp.Compiler.Service` wants.... I'm not sure how to fix that though!

Comment: (Although, I guess `LongIdent` is just a type alias for a `list` too - but maybe the issue is mismatch between the `list` used in `LongIdent` and `list` expected by `List.map` - it is quite strange!)

Comment: @TomasPetricek ah, your comment makes sense. Still not sure how to approach fixing it, but it's helpful :)

Comment: OK, not a "solution" in general, but at least by reverting to "FSharp.Compiler.Service": "9.0.1" I got things back working.

Comment: @Mathias I also faced the similar issue and posted the answer. please check if it helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is that Azure Functions SDK depend on [FSharp.Compiler.Service (FCS) version 9.0.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/072975d39a36c87cfc024a6d8d8b9109c84321bb/src/WebJobs.Script.NuGet/WebJobs.Script.nuspec#L30). This means that when you try to load a different version of FCS, you will get the already loaded version 9.0.1.

This works as long as the public API of the FCS version you are using matches the public API of version 9.0.1, but when there are differences, it will crash, because your code assumes that the public API looks different. I suppose this might be triggering the issue here, although I'm not 100% sure how (possibly, `LongIdent` is now a different thing than it was in version 9.0.1?)

The very same issue [used to happen with FAKE](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1096), which also bundles FCS and prevented loading of different versions. One of the options is to [rename the assembly to avoid the clash](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/pull/1097).

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error, I solved it by doing the following workaround, please refer if it works for you also.

- Right-click on the Project and select properties.
- Goto Debug tab and create a profile with the reference to the below
  screenshot.

**Note**: Replace UserName with your username.

[image: Project Properties]